# Globalise functions in a Webpack export (Laravel)?

Tags: laravel, webpack

I am using Laravel's Webpack implementation to compile assets into a single file. I have some custom functions stored in individual files..

```
require('./vendor/some-function.js');

$(document).ready(function() {
    someFunction();
});
```

In console log I'll get `undefined function someFunction.`

If I manually copy the code into the same file that the function is called it works.

Looking at compiled asset file it looks like Webpack is putting each required file in separate functions - I can only assume the function is not global.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: add the some-function.js in js folder and include it.

Comment: Is that not what I am already doing? I can see the function is included in compiled source but it's not available to to other areas of the code.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/some-function.js') }}"></script>` add the script like this and please let me know if it's working